# Why does pushing params with $router.push not add params to URL in Nuxt 3

Tags: vue-router, nuxtjs3

I have a Nuxt3 app and from a component I have:

```
this.$router.push(
     {
         name: "tmpchat",
         query: { nickname: this.nickname }
     }                    
);
```

The page changes, but it doesn't have the `?nickname=johnny` part.
In the `tmpchat` page on mounted I have: `console.log(this.$route.query.nickname);` and all I get is `undefined`.

When I manually add the `?nickname=johnny` part directly in URL then I get the desired output.

What can be the problem here?